# ASUS "FTE1000:00 0B05:0101" touchpad scroll option not working

Tags: touchpad, asus

I have an ASUS E402S laptop with Ubuntu 64-bit 16.04 LTS installed. The main problem is that the OS does recognize the touchpad with basic functions, but additional options such as scrolling through pages or between open applications are non-existent.

This is what my `xinput` result is showing:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1000:00 0B05:0101                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Apparently my touchpad's type is not shown in the list. What are the possible solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: The touchpad is shown. It is `FTE1000:00 0B05:0101 `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a new AzurWave i2c touchpad that is used in new Asus laptops. Current Linux kernels do not fully support this device.

You can install a driver for this touchpad this way.

Disable SecureBoot in BIOS and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms.git
cd hid-asus-dkms
./dkms-add.sh
```

Then reboot.

This is a new driver for the device. It has been accepted by kernel maintainers and it should appear upsream in the 4.10 Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another method to solve the problem.

The new drivers, as aforementioned earlier, will be included in Linux kernel 6.10.
However,at the time of writing this post the Linux kernel 6.10c is available.

Here's the guide to install it. Just install it and it should solve the problem.
http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2017/01/latest-kernel-410-rc3-released.html

Comment: What is Linux kernel 6.10?

Comment: There is no need to install a Release Candidate kernel just for one module.