# Touchpad Clicking not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after upgrading kernel from version 4.4.0-64 to 4.8.0-39

Tags: 16.04, grub2, kernel, mouse, touchpad

My touchpad clicking feature stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after i upgraded kernel from version 4.4.0-64 generic to 4.8.0-39 generic.Clicking is working fine with touchpad buttons but not with the main touchpad. I have to boot with the old kernel version through the grub menu while booting.

The output of the command `xinput` gives the output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The output of the command  $xinput list-props 11  gives the following output:

```
Device 'USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (257): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (258):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (259):    0, 0
    Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (261):    3034, 22494
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (262):    0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASUS "FTE1000:00 0B05:0101" touchpad scroll option not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/860314/asus-fte100000-0b050101-touchpad-scroll-option-not-working)

Comment: Install the driver from the duplicate link. The touchpad is detected as a mouse without it.

Comment: Can you please mention the duplicate link?

Comment: It is in the second comment.

Comment: And also run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`.

Comment: Even my previous kernel version stopped responding to touchpad clicking after installing your referred package!

Comment: Did you run the command I gave you in the previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I did run it.

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. You can always remove that driver. Please add output of `xinput list-props 11`

Comment: I see what is the problem. `libinput` is install. It is easy to fix. Do you have the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`?

Comment: And please run again `xinput`. It looks like the ID has changed.

Comment: bash: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf: Permission denied

Comment: It's OK. I am writing an answer that will fix it all.

Comment: And please run `xinput` again. Now the id of your touchpad is not 11. And then paste the output of `xinput list-props <your__touchpad_id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to the kernel upgrade. You installed `libinput`. Tapping is disabled there by default. It can be fixed this way. Run

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf
```

An editor window will open. Find the touchpad section in this file and add there a line

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

before `EndSection`.

Save the file and reboot. Tapping will be enabled.

Comment: Yes it finally worked! Thank you very much sir!

Comment: It was not related to the kernel upgrade. And now you have multitouch too.

Comment: Yupp! I wasn't able to use multitouch until this change. :)